# Search old distribution Linux container

Tags: docker

I need to get old 32 bit version Centos image and run in container on my Ubuntu system.

I do search for Centos:

```
sudo docker search centos
```

Found candidate:

```
NAME                               DESCRIPTION                                     STARS               OFFICIAL            AUTOMATED
centos                             The official build of CentOS.                   4100                [OK]
```

Download and run it:

```
sudo docker run centos
Unable to find image 'centos:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/centos
5e35d10a3eba: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:dcbc4e5e7052ea2306eed59563da1fec09196f2ecacbe042acbdcd2b44b05270
Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:latest
```

But I don't need latest centos. I would like to get list of available old Centos images.

How to get `Centos 6.9` image for container?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of available tags of the official CentOS 64 bit image using the following command:

```
curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/centos/tags | jq '.[] | (.name)' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

The output shows that there is CentOS image with the tag `centos6.9`.

Now you can run a container using something like:

```
docker run -ti centos:centos6.9 bash
```

You also can get a list of available tags of the official CentOS 32 bit image:

```
curl -s https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/i386/centos/tags | jq '.[] | (.name)' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
6
centos6
```

It seems an official repository with CentOS 32 bit version is abounded. Anyway you can try to start container with it.

Comment: What does first word `centos:` means in `centos:centos6.9`? In tags output I only see `centos6.9`

Comment: The first word `centos` means image name. In order to pull an image you should use a command `docker pull <image_name>:<tag>`.

Comment: I browsed to `https://hub.docker.com/r/i386/centos/` for Centos 32 bit immage. There I see two tags - `centos6` and `6`. But where is image name?

Comment: The image name is `i386/centos`.

Comment: linkrot: this url now returns 410 Gone